# Understanding SAS Mixed Model Syntax

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas

I'm used to specifying mixed models with mathematical notation or in R using the `lme4` syntax. Now, I was asked to review a mixed model fitted in SAS. The SAS model is specified as follows

```
PROC MIXED;
CLASS    animalID treatment week time_of_day;
MODEL    y = treatment week treatment*time_of_day
REPEATED time_of_day*week / SUBJECT=animalID TYPE=cs;
RANDOM   animalID(time_of_day);
```

I tried to translate this into `lme4` syntax (based on the [SAS Help Center: MIXED Procedure](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_mixed_syntax.htm) and [lmer for SAS PROC MIXED Users](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SASmixed/vignettes/Usinglmer.pdf)) and think the model above would correspond to the following model in `lme4`

```
lmer(y ~ treatment + treatment:time_of_day + week +
         (1|time_of_day:week) + (1|time_of_day:animalID))
```

with all predictors as factors.

Is this translation correct?

Specifically

1. Is it correct that `treatment*time_of_day` just includes the interaction but not the main effect of `treatment` and `time_of_day` in SAS?
2. An effect in the REPEATED statement with compound symmetry covariance structure is equivalent to a random intercept?
3. The nested notation (`animalID(time_of_day)`) just includes the random interaction between `animalID` and `time_of_day`? No additional main (random) effect of `time_of_day`?

Bonus Question: Do you know of any other good reference which directly compares how models in SAS and R are specified?

Comment: I'm not 100% on all of this, but: 1) correct, `treatment|time_of_day` would be the main plus interaction. 2) Only under non-negative correlation (which random effects don't allow) and I'm not sure if this applies if you have other random effects also. 3) This will make each unique combination of `animalID` and `time_of_day` a separate block in the random effect, I'm not used to this being called an interaction but I guess you could call it that, and definitely yes to the last part of your question.

Answer (score 7):

`Treatment * Time_of_day` Interaction: In SAS, the `treatment * time_of_day` term includes both the interaction and the main effects of treatment and time_of_day. In your lme4 translation, you've correctly included the interaction (treatment:time_of_day), but you should also include the main effects separately if you want them in the model. So, it should be:

```
lmer(y ~ treatment + time_of_day + treatment:time_of_day + week +
      (1 | time_of_day:week) + (1 | time_of_day:animalID))
```

This includes the main effects of treatment and time_of_day along with the interaction.

Effect in the `REPEATED` Statement: In SAS, the `REPEATED` statement with the `TYPE = cs` option specifies a compound symmetry covariance structure for the repeated measures. This is equivalent to having a random intercept for `time_of_day` in the `lme4` model. So, I think your translation is correct in including `(1 | time_of_day:week)`.

Nested Notation: Yes, `(1 | animalID(time_of_day))` in SAS includes the random interaction between `animalID` and `time_of_day`. It does not include an additional main (random) effect of time_of_day, so this seems correct to me.

As for resources, I find this quite helpful:

https://support.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/books/free-books/sas-programming-for-r-users.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about the automatic inclusion of interaction terms? All that I found so far suggests the opposite. See e.g. [SAS Documentation ANOVA Procedure](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_anova_details01.htm). They always explicitly write the main effects and additionally have the bar (|) notation which seems to be the equivalent of the asterisk (*) in R.

Comment: I’m not 100% sure to be honest. Thanks for bringing that up. These things are always a bit frustrating! It’s late here now but I will take another look tomorrow.

Comment: @retodomax sorry for the delay ! I have just had a chance to look at this again, and you are right.  In SAS, when you specify an interaction term using the asterisk (*), it does *not* automatically include the main effects. In SAS, if you want to include the main effects along with the interaction, you need to specify them explicitly. I will update the answer shortly.